# Instabot signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, flask

I am running a Flask application, using the Instabot library.

The Flask application has a form where the Instagram account and password is entered and submitted, once submitted, this method is called:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def post_to_insta():
    bot = Bot() 
    usr = request.form['username']
    pss = request.form['password']
    text = request.form['text']
    bot.login(username=usr, password=pss)
    bot.upload_photo("thisimage",  caption = text)
    return "Done!"
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

on this line:

```
bot.login(username=usr, password=pss)
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One parameter is missing, is_threaded

Just do:

```
bot.login(username=usr, password=pss, is_threaded=True)
```

Comment: setting ```is_threaded``` to True fixes this issue, thanks!